# puppeteer: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I came a across a website that puppeteer can't handle. When making screenshot, `Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed` or `Protocol error (Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Target closed` is triggered. Before taking a screenshot, I scroll it so that all images are loaded. The page is large so I set `'--disable-dev-shm-usage','--shm-size=3gb',` params in hope to prevent any memory issues. This is sample code with url included. Any idea why the page is closed in the middle of the operation?  In addition to puppeteer-cluster ("^0.23.0"), I am also using puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth("^2.9.0") and puppeteer-extra("^3.2.3")

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import {Cluster} from 'puppeteer-cluster';
import StealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());


const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    puppeteer,
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
    maxConcurrency: 1,
    puppeteerOptions:{
        headless : true,
        args: [
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--window-size=1920,1080',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--shm-size=3gb',
        ]
    }
   
  });

  await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    let response = await page.goto(url, { waitUntil:"networkidle2" });
    await Screenshot(page, screenshotPaths);  
  
  });




async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        try {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let totalHeight = 0;
                let distance = 389;
                let counter = 0;
                let timer = setInterval(() => {
                    counter++;
                    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;

                    if((totalHeight >= scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) || counter > 100){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 50);
            });

        }catch (e) {
            console.log("we got scrolling error:");
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}


async function Screenshot(page) {  

    let save = true;
    try {
        await page.waitForTimeout(6000);
        await page.setViewport({ width:390, height:844});
        await autoScroll(page);
        await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
        if(save) await page.screenshot({path: "./mobile.jpg",  fullPage: true});

        await page.setViewport({ width:1920, height:1080});
        await autoScroll(page);
        await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
        if(save) await page.screenshot({path: "./desktop.jpg",  fullPage: true});
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("we got screenshot error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}


  cluster.queue("https://www.sinsay.com/si/sl/sale/woman/view-all-clothes");
  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
```

stack trace:

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
    at /path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:230:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:226:16)
    at next (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/sourceurl/index.js:32:41)
    at CDPSession.send (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/sourceurl/index.js:65:16)
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:204:50)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:27)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (/path/to/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:123:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  originalMessage: ''
}
```

---